# Set cookie in axios not working on cross domain request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios, setcookie

i have a simple react client with axios on localhost , on other side i have python fastapi in the server side ( both https) . server side is setting a none httponly cookie , clientside receive it but won't set it . here is my response:

```
access-control-allow-credentials
    true
access-control-allow-origin
    https://localhost
access-control-expose-headers
    set-cookie
content-length
    52
content-type
    application/json
date
    Sun, 19 Sep 2021 12:46:09 GMT
server
    uvicorn
set-cookie
    fakesession=fake-cookie-session-value; Max-Age=100000000; Path=/; SameSite=none; Secure
vary
    Origin
```

here is my client side code :

```
export const AxTest =  axios.create({
  //baseURL: "https://localhost:6069",
  baseURL: "https://***.***.***.***:3002",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

cookie is not set , i don't receive any error and the response code is 200.
document.cookie is empty .
by the way i have tried both on my localhost ( python and react running on localhost ) it was setting cookie successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when

- front request axios => baseURL from localhost to 192.168.1.1
- if u are sending the request in "chrome... " with URL

  - "http://localhost" instead of "ip=http://192.168.1.1"
- backend config - request accepted origin - add the "ip=192.168.1.1"
- config secure from setCookie : false or true if u are using https .
  Summary
  If u are using front with localhost, config the fetch "axios" with baseURL localhost or change the baseURL with the ip/url that u want